# Update specific line on Console

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console

Is it possible for a C# console application to update the the corresponding line from multi-thread?

Something like this

```
thread 1: 1 of 100 
thread 2: 2 of 2004
thread 3: Initialize
thread 4: Complete
```

Need for updating each line.

---

***Update***

I think I am closing to the Answser.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netcore-3.1

1.Get A new CursorPosition(ex:LastLine) for each  thread and hold.

2.Use Console.SetCursorPosition(int,int) to Update the corresponding line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method `Console.SetCursorPosition` to set the cursor position and then call `Console.Write`, that will write starting at the position set.

Something like:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0); // for line 1
Console.Write($"thread 1: {current1} of {total1}");
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1); // for line 2
Console.Write($"thread 2: {current2} of {total2}");
```